# Function is affecting two sprites in simple JavaScript game

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on a simple Google dino clone in JavaScript.  At this point, an obstacle block is moving on the ground from right to left, and you can jump over it.  I want to add a feature where the obstacle block will either be on the ground (you have to jump) or in the air (you have to duck).

I have a function written to make the character jump, which works just fine.  I have also written a function to make the character duck. When you do this, the character sprite ducks as expected, but the obstacle moves up at the same time.

The "duck" function should only affect the "sprite" div, but it is also affecting the "obstacle" div, but in reverse (it's "jumping" when it should stay level).  I've combed over my code, and I can't see any reason why that is happening.  Any ideas?

```js
var sprite = document.querySelector('#sprite');
var jumpButton = document.querySelector('#jump');
var duckButton = document.querySelector('#duck');

function jump() {
  sprite.classList.add('jump');
  setTimeout(function() {
    sprite.classList.remove('jump');
  }, 750);
}

function duck() {
  sprite.classList.add('duck');
  setTimeout(function() {
    sprite.classList.remove('duck');
  }, 750);
}

jumpButton.addEventListener('click', jump);
duckButton.addEventListener('click', duck);
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: #373b47;
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#container {
  margin: 30px auto 0 auto;
  height: 200px;
  width: 500px;
  border: 1px solid #ffffff;
  background-color: #0d003c;
}

#sprite {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #2897bf;
  position: relative;
  top: 150px;
}

@keyframes jump {
  0% {
    top: 150px;
  }

  30% {
    top: 100px;
  }
  
  70% {
    top: 110px;
  }

  100% {
    top: 150px;
  }
}

@keyframes duck {
  0% {
    height: 50px;
    top: 150px;
  }

  50% {
    height: 25px;
    top: 175px;
  }

  100% {
    height: 50px;
    top: 150px;
  }
}

.jump {
  animation: jump 1s;
}

.duck {
  animation: duck 1s;
}

#obstacle {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background-color: #afafc2;
  position: relative;
  top: 125px;
  left: 475px;
  animation: move 1s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes move {
  0% {
    left: 475px;
  }

  100% {
    left: 0px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="sprite"></div>
  <div id="obstacle"></div>
</div>
<div id="controls">
  <button id="jump">Jump</button>
  <button id="duck">Duck</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the clear question and a demo. It's normal behavior as the position of the sprite is relative to the container and when the obstacle is moved, it moves according to the items of the container. You can try with [`position: sticky`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position), adjust the top value, and see if it solves your problem.

Comment: Thank you!  This helped me understand the concepts so much better.  It now makes sense that the obstacle is moving due to the relative positioning.  This knowledge combined with the other comments below helped me fix the issue!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you made a mistake in your `CSS` code. You should set the `position` property of your container to `relative`, and set the position of other elements to `absolute`. Also, you should set the bottom value to 0 for both elements so that they are positioned at the `bottom` of your container. Now, you can use keyframes to change the `top` property, and these changes will not affect each other. Therefore, your CSS file should be modified as follows:

```js
var sprite = document.querySelector('#sprite');
var jumpButton = document.querySelector('#jump');
var duckButton = document.querySelector('#duck');

function jump() {
  sprite.classList.add('jump');
  setTimeout(function() {
    sprite.classList.remove('jump');
  }, 750);
}

function duck() {
  sprite.classList.add('duck');
  setTimeout(function() {
    sprite.classList.remove('duck');
  }, 750);
}

jumpButton.addEventListener('click', jump);
duckButton.addEventListener('click', duck);
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: #373b47;
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#container {
  position:relative;
  margin: 30px auto 0 auto;
  height: 200px;
  width: 500px;
  border: 1px solid #ffffff;
  background-color: #0d003c;
  overflow-y:hidden;
}

#sprite {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #2897bf;
  position: absolute;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
}

@keyframes jump {
  0% {
    top: 150px;
  }

  30% {
    top: 100px;
  }
  
  70% {
    top: 110px;
  }

  100% {
    top: 150px;
  }
}

@keyframes duck {
  0% {
    height: 50px;
    top: 150px;
  }

  50% {
    height: 25px;
    top: 175px;
  }

  100% {
    height: 50px;
    top: 150px;
  }
}

.jump {
  animation: jump 1s;
}

.duck {
  animation: duck 1s;
}

#obstacle {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background-color: #afafc2;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 475px;
  animation: move 1s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes move {
  0% {
    left: 475px;
  }

  100% {
    left: 0px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
<div id="sprite"></div>
<div id="obstacle"></div>
</div>
<div id="controls">
<button id="jump">Jump</button>
<button id="duck">Duck</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey Milad, It would be nice if you can edit your answer describing what was changed and maybe why it happened so that it may be useful for future readers.

Comment: Hey, i edited it.

Comment: This worked! Changing the sprite positions to absolute and the container position to relative fixed the issue!  Thanks so much! This community is awesome.